# HashBasedTable Table<String, String, Double> employeeYearsOfService and HashMap<String, Double> hm1 java

Tags: java, hashmap, guava

I have  `HashBasedTable  Table<String, String, Double> employeeYearsOfService`

```
 AT&T={Bill Smith=2.0, Stacy Lerner=1.4},
 fatima={Bill Smith=1.0, Stacy Lerner=2.0}
```

and I have  `HashMap<String, Double> hm1` who has same keyRows of `employeeYearsOfService`

```
AT&T=0.9628,
fatima=0.975
```

I want to do this calculation

```
result= 2.0*0968+1.0*0.975| for column bill Smith
result= 1.4*0968+2.0*0.975| for column Stacy Lerner
```

and stock the result in new hashmap hm4

### My Code

```
//my table guava
Table <String,String,Double> employeeYearsOfService = HashBasedTable.create();

employeeYearsOfService.put("AT&T", "Stacy Lerner", 1.4);
employeeYearsOfService.put("AT&T", "Bill Smith", 2.0);
employeeYearsOfService.put("fatima", "Bill Smith", 1.0);
employeeYearsOfService.put("fatima", "Stacy Lerner", 2.0);
System.out.println("la matrice des notes");
System.out.println(employeeYearsOfService);
//my hashmap
HashMap <String,Double> hm1 = new HashMap <String,Double>();
hm1.put(AT & T, 0.962);
hm1.put(fatima, 0.975);
System.out.println(hm1);
```

my loop for the calul

```
Double res = 0.0;

for (String ke : employeeYearsOfService.columnKeySet()) {

    for (Entry<String, Double> employeek : 
       employeeYearsOfService.column(ke).entrySet()) {
        for (Double mapValue : hm1.values()) {

            res+ = employeek.getValue() *mapValue.doubleValue();

        }

        hm4.put(ke, res);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that it does not calculate what I want

```
result= (2.0*0968+2.0*0.975)+(1.0*0968+1.0*0.975)| for column bill Smith
```

thank you

Comment: And what do you want to see as output?

Comment: @RobinTopper i want get the result of calul and same key in my `HashMap hm1`

Comment: Your question and expected results are still not clear to me. Try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: ok i will try thank you Robin